# Error "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Blink" in installation

Tags: julia, blink

I am trying to install Blink and getting the following message.

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Blink
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Blink [ad839575]:
 Blink [ad839575] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0-0.1.5, 0.2.0-0.2.1, 0.3.0-0.3.5, 0.4.0-0.4.4, 0.5.0-0.5.4, 0.6.0-0.6.2, 0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.1.0-0.1.5, 0.2.0-0.2.1, 0.3.0-0.3.5, 0.4.0-0.4.4, 0.5.0-0.5.4, 0.6.0-0.6.2, 0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0]
 ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0]
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with HttpServer [58cfbd8c] to versions: [0.1.0-0.1.5, 0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.8.0-0.8.1, 0.9.0]
 │ └─HttpServer [58cfbd8c] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1-0.0.14, 0.1.0-0.1.7, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.1] or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with WebSockets [104b5d7c] to versions: 0.1.0-0.1.5 or uninstalled — no versions left
   └─WebSockets [104b5d7c] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1-0.0.6, 0.1.0-0.1.2, 0.2.0-0.2.3, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 1.0.0-1.0.3, 1.1.0-1.1.1, 1.2.0] or uninstalled
     ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with HTTP [cd3eb016] to versions: [0.0.1-0.0.6, 0.1.0-0.1.2, 0.2.0-0.2.3, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0] or uninstalled
     │ └─HTTP [cd3eb016] log:
     │   ├─possible versions are: [0.0.1-0.0.2, 0.4.0-0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.5.2-0.5.5, 0.5.7, 0.6.0-0.6.14, 0.7.0-0.7.1, 0.8.0] or uninstalled
     │   └─restricted to versions 0.8.0 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.8.0
     └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [1.0.0-1.0.3, 1.1.0-1.1.1, 1.2.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: uninstalled
```

I am not sure how to decipher, given the following packages installed.

```
(v1.0) pkg> status
    Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.7.6
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.4.3
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.17.1
  [cd3eb016] HTTP v0.8.0
  [0862f596] HTTPClient v0.2.1
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.16.0
  [682c06a0] JSON v0.20.0
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.5.4
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v0.23.0
  [f3b207a7] StatsPlots v0.10.1
  [ddb6d928] YAML v0.3.2
  [ade2ca70] Dates
```

Do I need to install HTTPServer and Websockets packages?

HTTP.jl version is v0.8.0 and it should meet requirement, no?

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.0.3
Commit 099e826241 (2018-12-18 01:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, sandybridge)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = atom -a
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 2
```

Comment: I managed to install it (although on Windows). Seems you could have run into some dependency spaghetti. Try using a fresh library folder (run `export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/home/yourusername/somefolder"`), run `julia`, check if depot path configuration worked (should be visible at `versioninfo()`) and now retry installing `Blink.jl`

Comment: Also on your old package folder I would try running `using Pkg` and `Pkg.update()`.

Comment: Hello Przemyslaw! Thanks for your reply. First of all, I have issued the update command, but "add Blink" spits out the same error. Unfortunately I am very new to Julia and need a bit of hand-holdings from you. 1) Normally the update command installs packages on ~/.julia/packages/, but your suggestion is to do so somewhere else by specifying another path with JULIA_DEPOT_PATH. What is the purpose of this? 2) In resolving my dependency issue, how is creating a new library folder different from creating a new environment? Any pros and cons? Thanks

Comment: I could install Blink so it means that it should be possible. My guess is that you might have installed something with non matching dependencies. Hence, advised you to "start from scratch". I case of Julia you do not need to reinstall to start from scratch - just st a new `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`

Comment: Here is what I have done. On my MX Linux Terminal, I have issued "export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH='/opt/julia/' and see that result with the 'env' command. GREAT! I then launched a new Atom session and typed in versioninfo() in REPL, yet JULIA_DEPOT_PATH is NOT shown... I tried my luck by issuing the "add Blink" command, but in vain with the same errors as before. Interestingly I do not have the ~/.julia/config/ directory, in which startup.jl resides, making me wonder where JULIA_EDITOR and JULIA_NUM_THREADS are loaded from...

Comment: `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH='/opt/julia/'` is a very bad directory name for storing Julia packages. Use something like `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/home/yourusername/somefolder"` Of course create an empty directory `/home/yourusername/somefolder`